# C++ - Casting void pointer

Tags: c++, polymorphism, void-pointers

Does C++ throw runtime exceptions when you try to cast a `void*` to something that it isn't?

```
class Sheep
{
public:
    Sheep() { }

    ~Sheep() { }

    void Bah()
    {
        // Print Bah!
    }
};

class Unicorn
{
    Unicorn() { }

    ~Unicorn() { }

    void Stab(Sheep* s)
    {
        s->Bah();
    }
};


int main()
{
    Sheep sheep;

    void* ptr = (void*) &s;

    // I'm guessing this would be 'valid'
    Unicorn* unicorn = (Unicorn*) ptr;
    // This must go wrong..?
    unicorn->Stab(&sheep);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jfs: I ran this sort of scenario on Windows and it doesn't complain. I was wondering if it's defined behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does C++ throw runtime exceptions when you try to cast a `void*` to something that it isn't?

No, it doesn't.

The behavior of your program is undefined:  anything could happen.  The program might appear to work most of the time, it might crash at any point, or something worse might happen.

`void*` should be avoided in all but a few rare cases in C++; instead of resorting to using `void*`, you should consider using class inheritance, polymorphism, or templates to be sure that your code is type safe.  While C++ does allow you to write code that is not type safe, it also provides many tools that help you to write type safe code and make that code much more straightforward, simple, and correct.

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you could not cast a void*. what could you do with it!?  In fact you *must* cast it in order to assign it to a pointer of some other type or dereference it.

In your example you used a C style cast, C++ supports several safer cast operators such as [`dynamic_cast`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/dynamic_cast) which *does* test the validity of the cast at run-time.

Comment: Should I be using those functions in C++ instead of `(Type)` casts?

Comment: @Kevin:  In general, yes; but they are not functions they *are* type casts, but each one has specific restrictions that make them safer by indicating intent rather then the brute-force do it regardless C style cast.

Comment: This is a different sort of casting than is normally used with `void*`. It is perfectly acceptable to cast a `void*` to its original type, but casting it to a different type (as the OP's example shows) will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @Eva: Good point.  I merely answered explicit the question in the text, not the implicit question in the example.  You point is well covered in the accepted answer, so I'll let it stand as is.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.
That's why using `void*` in C++ is bad practice.

Use templates instead of `void*`. they are type safe.

`void*` should be used only  when you are dealing with C code.

Answer (score -1):

No. either in C or in C++
this is a basic operation we can do in this language.

Comment: This causes undefined behavior, so it is not a basic operation but rather a programming error.